# How to save passwords in MySQL database using Asp.Net in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, password-encryption, saltedhash

What method is best suitable theses days for saving salted/hashed passwords in a database? I am thinking about BCrypt or SHA51 or PBKDF2, which one is best suited?

And someone please tell me how to implement them in Mysql database using Asp.net in C#.

Comment: Your first part is suitable for one question, although this may be more of a preference depending on the nature of your project.  The second part is entirely too broad to address in one post.

Comment: Just using a hash function such as SHA512 is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead use a function with a random salt and a computational time of about 100ms duration, save the salt and iteration count with the hash.

Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions.

The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force from a frequent password list.

Comment: [NIST](https://www.nist.gov) currently recommends `PBKDF2`. See [Recommendation for Password-Based Key Derivation](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to save passwords in a database?

If you have to ask, you **definitely** don't want to implement this yourself.

> How to implement [this] using ASP.NET

You're lucky, they already did that for you. It's called [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) and is usable with about any ORM and RDBMS you can think of.

Again, you do **not** want to deal with the saving of passwords yourself.